# Unable to migrate customer data (1.9 to 2.0)

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, data-migration

I am able to Migrate my Old Data from `Magento v-1.9.2.4 to Magento V-2.1.0` using Default Data Migration Tool.

Followed the steps, ignored the fields and tables of Third-Party modules and everything was pretty smooth.

All of the Orders, Settings, Pages etc. are migrated properly except Customers data.

There are `currently 0 customers showing in Magento V-2.1 panel` when there are more than 10K customers in reality.

Can someone point me out if I am doing anything wrong? or maybe I ignored a tablename in map file which caused this.

Comment: i hope you might have done, just reindex and check.

Comment: worked out?????

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar yes. your solution was correct.

Comment: @A.Agg , if you found a solution or comment working always tries to close the question as it make SE clean and it help other user as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [After Migration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-after.html) steps.

1. Put Magento 1 in maintenance mode and permanently stop all Admin
   activities
2. Start Magento 2 cron jobs
3. Flush all Magento 2 cache types
   How to  [flush](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean) ?

**Cache Clean Using Command Line**

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

**Cache Flush Using Command Line**

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

4. Reindex all Magento 2 indexers

**Reindexing Using Command Line**

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

5. Change DNS, load balancers, etc. to point to Magento 2 production
   hardware